# How to open BottomNavigationView's fragment in activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to call method 
***showNewsPageTime()*** 
from **MainFragment.kt** in AlertBoxActivity.kt to open 
**newsFragment**, 
but app has stopped.

`MainFragment.kt`

(`BottomNavigationView` located here. I want to open `NewsFragment` page from here, because if i'll open it directly bottom navigation disappears.)

```
package kz.app.fragment
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
import android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources
import android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import kotlin.concurrent.schedule
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_main.view.*
import kz.app.R
import kz.app.model.MainViewModel
import kz.app.model.Stat## Heading ##eViewModel
import kz.app.repository.PreferencesRepository
import kz.app.util.OnBackPressDelegate
import kz.app.util.bind
import kz.app.util.setBadge


class MainFragment : Fragment(), BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnBackPressDelegate, DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {
    private val model by lazy { StateViewModel.get<MainViewModel>(this) }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val imm = context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)
        retainInstance = true
        if (!PreferencesRepository.getInstance(context
                        ?: return).isTutorialFinished.blockingFirst())
            InstructionFragment().show(childFragmentManager)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        view.bottomNavigation.initMenu()
        view.bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        view.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { view.drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START) }
        view.pickCity.setOnClickListener { _ -> CityPickerDialogFragment.show(childFragmentManager) { model.setCurrentCity(it.id) } }
        view.pickCity.bind(model.currentCityIconResId) { setImageResource(it) }
        view.flipper.displayedChild = savedInstanceState?.getInt(KEY_CURRENT_ITEM, 0) ?: 0
        view.bottomNavigation.run {
            selectedItemId = menu.getItem(view.flipper.displayedChild).itemId
        }
        view.drawer.addDrawerListener(this)
        view.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            val currentPage = view?.flipper?.displayedChild
                    ?: return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false
            val shoppingFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.shoppingFragment)
            val newsFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsFragment)
            val bonusFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bonusFragment)
            val notificationsFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.notificationsFragment)
            val helpFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.helpFragment)
            when (currentPage) {
                0 -> shoppingFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(it)
                1 -> newsFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(it)
                2 -> bonusFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(it)
                3 -> helpFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(it)
                4 -> notificationsFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(it)
                else -> false
            }
        }


        return view
    }

    fun showBonusesPage() {
        view?.flipper?.displayedChild = 2
        view?.bottomNavigation?.selectedItemId = R.id.bonus
    }

    fun showNewsPage() {
        view?.flipper?.displayedChild = 1

        view?.bottomNavigation?.selectedItemId = R.id.news
        System.out.println("HEloo")
    }
//this method should be called in AlertBoxActivity
    fun showNewsPageTime() {
        var newsFragment = 1
        childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsFragment)
        InstructionFragment().show(childFragmentManager)
    }




    private fun BottomNavigationView.initMenu() {
        menu.clear()
        menu.add(0, R.id.main, 0, R.string.main).icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_shopping)
        menu.add(0, R.id.news, 0, R.string.news).icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_news)
        menu.add(0, R.id.bonus, 0, R.string.bonus).icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_bonus)
        menu.add(0, R.id.help, 0, R.string.help).icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_help)
        menu.add(0, R.id.notifications, 0, R.string.notifications).icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_notification)
        bind(model.unreadCount) { setBadge(R.id.notifications, if (it > 0) it.toString() else null) }
    }

    override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) {

    }

    override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {

    }

    override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
        try {
            childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_main)?.userVisibleHint = false
        } catch (_: IllegalStateException) {
        }
    }

    override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
        try {
            childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_main)?.userVisibleHint = true
        } catch (_: java.lang.IllegalStateException) {
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        updateTitle()
    }

    private fun updateTitle() {
        when (view?.flipper?.displayedChild) {
            0 -> view?.toolbar?.setTitle(R.string.your_bright_shopping)
            1 -> view?.toolbar?.setTitle(R.string.news)
            2 -> view?.toolbar?.setTitle(R.string.bonus)
            3 -> view?.toolbar?.setTitle(R.string.help)
            4 -> view?.toolbar?.setTitle(R.string.notifications)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun notifyFragments() {
        val currentPage = view?.flipper?.displayedChild ?: return
        val shoppingFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.shoppingFragment)
        val newsFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsFragment)
        val bonusFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bonusFragment)
        val notificationsFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.notificationsFragment)
        val helpFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.helpFragment)
        shoppingFragment?.userVisibleHint = currentPage == 0
        newsFragment?.userVisibleHint = currentPage == 1
        bonusFragment?.userVisibleHint = currentPage == 2
        helpFragment?.userVisibleHint = currentPage == 3
        notificationsFragment?.userVisibleHint = currentPage == 4
        val menu = view?.toolbar?.menu ?: return
        val inflater = SupportMenuInflater(view?.toolbar?.context)
        menu.clear()
        when (currentPage) {
            0 -> shoppingFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
            1 -> newsFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
            2 -> bonusFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
            3 -> helpFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
            4 -> notificationsFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putInt(KEY_CURRENT_ITEM, view?.flipper?.displayedChild ?: 0)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
        val drawer = view?.drawer ?: return false
        return when {
            drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START) -> {
                drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START)
                true
            }
            view?.bottomNavigation?.selectedItemId == R.id.main -> false
            else -> {
                view?.bottomNavigation?.selectedItemId = R.id.main
                true
            }
        }
    }

     fun onBackPressedNews(): Boolean {

                view?.bottomNavigation?.selectedItemId = R.id.news

            return true

    }


    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val page = when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.main -> 0
            R.id.news -> 1
            R.id.bonus -> 2
            R.id.help -> 3
            R.id.notifications -> 4
            else -> return false
        }
        view?.flipper?.displayedChild = page
        updateTitle()
        notifyFragments()
        return true
    }


    companion object {
        private const val KEY_CURRENT_ITEM = "current_item"
    }

}
```

`AlertBoxActivity.kt`

Activity where I call `showNewsPageTime()` method, but when running android has stopped.

```
    package kz.app

    import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_main.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_parking_payment.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_shopping.*
    import kz.app.api.entity.PromoAction
    import kz.app.model.PromoActionViewModel
    import kz.app.fragment.NewsFragment
    import kz.app.fragment.PromoDetailsFragment
    import kz.app.fragment.MainFragment
    import kz.app.fragment.ShoppingDetailsFragment
    import kz.app.model.PromoDetailsViewModel
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.R

    class AlertBoxActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val obj = MainFragment()
            obj.showNewsPageTime()
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(android.R.id.content, obj)
                        .commit()
```